# Two parallel lines between two nodes using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I'm trying to make a visualization of a center node that's connected to nodes around it. Currently, there's one line between the center node and each of the other nodes. I would like to change that into two parallel lines with different width and color (one showing information about calls and one showing information about texts). **It's important that the two lines fit exactly next to each other with no space between them and no overlap**.

**EDIT:** The answer from mdml and comments from LarsKotthoff helped me. However, I'm still facing some issues as seen in the comments: The offset seems to push the two lines in the direction of the bigger line (see imgur.com/Fwri75T). I really can't understand. I've updated the code here. Full code can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/xykoln14euewm9z/Network%20View%20v2.zip?dl=0

```
 function total_width(d)  {
 return (d.inc_calls + d.out_calls + d.inc_texts + d.out_texts) / max_interactions * line_width_factor; 
 }

 var line_diff   = 1;

 function line_perpendicular_shift(d, direction) {
    theta = getAngle(d);
    theta_perpendicular = theta + (Math.PI / 2)*direction;


    width = total_width(d) + line_diff

    // Both lines are pushed 1/4, moving the center by 1/2, causing the two lines to connect exactly at the middle.
    delta_x = width / 4 * Math.cos(theta_perpendicular) 
    delta_y = width / 4 * Math.sin(theta_perpendicular)

    return [delta_x, delta_y]

 }
```

Comment: I would add a second line in exactly the same way as the first with start and end positions slightly shifted.

Comment: How would you ensure that the lines don't overlap?

Comment: This is determine by how much you shift the positions.

Comment: Maybe I'm just blanking, but what would be the correct formula for making them appear next to each other? I assume it would involve the width of the two lines and the angle between the two nodes.

Comment: You would shift the points along the line perpendicular to the line that connects them. The amount of shift directly translates to the distance between them and therefore the width you can use without them overlapping.

Comment: I've tried to implement it based on your comments. Can you spot the error?

Comment: Sign error in `Math.atan2`: http://jsfiddle.net/La4tavb7/

Comment: Ah, I must have copy-pasted without thinking. What answer should I choose now? mdml's answer is likely confusing for others as the question has changed.

Comment: It shouldn't. May be an optical illusion. In any case, you can easily adjust.

Comment: I'm creating an overlay of the two lines with a third (mostly transparent) line to mark information about the relationship between the two nodes (see http://imgur.com/Fwri75T). The third line is simply between the center coords of the two nodes, nothing special going on. As you especially can see in the bottom-right corner the two lines are off towards the bigger line. How would you adjust the code?

Comment: Probably a bug in how the offset is computed related to the width of the line.

Comment: I've been looking at it for a couple of days now, but can't find the error. But I have isolated it to the line_perpendicular_shift function seen above (if I multiply delta_x and delta_y by 0 before returning the values, the problem disappears). Can you take another look at the problem?

Comment: Well what code are you using exactly? The last jsfiddle assumes that both lines have the same width.

Comment: I've edited my question to have the code used for creating the offset. In a zip-file is all of the code including .csv-files (I don't know how to include .csv-files in jsfiddle). See imgur.com/Fwri75T for an illustration - the two lines no longer have same width.

Comment: In your changed source you're still assuming that both lines have the same width. The shift is determined by the maximum width -- you need to refactor so that the function that computes the shift takes the width of the line into account (wider lines need to be shifted by more).

Comment: Can you give me a hint to the formula that computes the shift while taking  the width into account?

Comment: I would make the shift a factor to be multiplied by the width. To start, you could simply do that with the current shift.

Comment: I found a solution after making a lot of simplified examples :) The shift for each line is simply the width of the opposite line divided by 2.